# Restriction of function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $A ⊆ B ⊆\mathbb{R}$, let $f: B→\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ be restriction of $f$ to $A$(that is, $g(x) = f(x)$ for $x∈A$) then,
a) if $f$ is continuous at $c∈ A$ then, g is continuous at $c$.
b)Show by example that, if $g$ is continuous at point $c$ , it need not follow $f$ is continuous at $c$.

(Excercise Reference: introduction to Real analysis, Bartle sec 5.1)

**My attempt**:

**a)** given $f$ is continuous at **$c∈ A$**, hence $$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$$

Now,

$$\lim_{x\to c}g(x) =\lim_{x\to c}f(x)= f(c)=g(c)$$

(Since, $g(x) = f(x)$ if $x∈A$)

So that, $g$  must be continuous at $c$.

**(b)** I am stuck here, is b) is wrong? I mean, how could be, restriction is continuous but function is not continuous? Or I am not able to  find such example! Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\colon x\geq 0\}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}$ and

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,  & x\geq 0 \\
0, & x<0
\end{cases}$$

Its restriction to $A$ is continuous (it is constant on $A$), but it is not continuous on $B$, as it has a jump discontinuity at $0$.