# Restriction of the Dirichlet function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq \mathbb R$, let $f : B \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and let g be the restriction of f to A ( that is, $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x \in A$)

Show by example that if g is continuous at c, it need not follow that f is continuous
at c

I know a similar question has been asked here [Restriction of function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607244/restriction-of-function)

But what I wanted to know is whether my attempt is correct.

**My attempt**

Consider the Dirichlet function

$f(x) = 1 \ ; \  x \in \mathbb Q $
$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = 0 \ ; \ x \notin \mathbb Q$

Let $A = \mathbb Q, \ B = \mathbb R$

So the restriction to $A$, g will be a continous function since it is constant, however f is not constant.

Can this be considered a valid example.

Comment: Tanisha, yes, your counterexample is correct.